# proxy: error reading status line from remote server

Tags: apache, web-services, ssl, client

I got this kind of Apache Proxy error in SSL_ERROR_LOG file.

```
[Mon Jul 18 11:03:52 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server [serverIP]
[Mon Jul 18 11:03:52 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /project/webservice
[Mon Jul 18 11:12:53 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server [serverIP]
[Mon Jul 18 11:12:53 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /project/webservice
[Mon Jul 18 11:15:53 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server [serverIP]
[Mon Jul 18 11:15:53 2016] [error] [client [IPAddress]] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /project/webservice
```

Any idea for this kind of error?  Client have to waits 3 minutes for a response before disconnecting forcibly. This error occurred after ssl certificate changed. We have updated certificate with SHA-1 to SHA-2 which is compatible with all browser.
Various timeouts have been observed and logged.

Comment: And Client got this error 2016-07-21 06:03:08|ERROR|System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:02:59.9531244. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.--->System.TimeoutException:The HTTP request to 'weburl' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:03:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.System.Net.WebException:The operation has timed out

Answer (score 0):

Check if SELinux is installed, if so then enable httpd using the below command -

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```